# pass an event AND a variable to an anon function in firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, closures

I come again with my inabilities to comprehend javascript.

I have a draggable library and it has a command that is called like so (the _ag is just namespacing stuff):

```
_ag.drag(event,targetDiv);  
// targetDiv can be a string, btw - converted to an element in the function
```

so I've got code that looks like so (passing some data with a closure - a new trick to me):

```
header.onmousedown=function(targetDiv){
    return function(){
        _ag.drag(event,targetDiv)
    }

}(aTargetDiv)
```

works great!  just great!  in...IE!  SF!  Chrome!  NOT IN FIREFOX!

No, firefox cannot find the event.  Now normally this is easy enough with something like this (formed slightly differently - hope it's still valid):

```
header.onmousedown=function(event){
    alert(event.screenX)
}
```

However if I decide to pass some parameters in, it blows away event, which I guess is some sort of invisible parameter in FF?

```
//broken thing 1:
header.onmousedown=function(event){
    alert(event.screenX)    //  somethingToPass in covers event in FF
}(somethingToPassIn)


// broken thing 2:
header.onmousedown=function(event){
    alert(event.screenX)    
}(event,somethingToPassIn)  // event is undefined
```

SO FIREFOX: How do I send you events?  Here's hoping this is a very stupid question, and that hoards of SO folks have the answers!  Thanks in advance, I'll be right here banging my head against the wall.

Comment: It cannot find `event` because you did not specify it as parameter. In W3C compatible browsers, the `event` object is the first parameter passed to an event handler. IE went another way by providing it only via `window.event`. Chrome does both. I suggest you read the [excellent articles about event handling at quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firefox probably doesn't have support for `event`, but instead passes it into your function when the event fires. So,

```
header.onmousedown=function(targetDiv){
    return function(e){
        e = e || event;  //This will give support for global event and passing the event into the function
        _ag.drag(e, targetDiv);
    }
}(aTargetDiv)
```

You don't need the closure unless the `aTargetDiv` variable changes sometime later in the code. Instead, you could do:

```
header.onmousedown=function(e){
    e = e || event;
    _ag.drag(e, aTargetDiv);
};
```

Comment: Holy shart!  It works!  Also: the thing is applied dynamically all over the place, so "aTargetDiv" can be different depending on the context.  (art school - a fine background for this sort of thing)  Thanks!